# Working with a large number of text labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, label

This code snippet with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.5 produces a responsive visualization on modern PC when `size` is small. When it gets near 20, there is a noticeable lag.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

size = 8
data = np.random.rand(size, size)
plt.imshow(data, origin='lower', interpolation='None', aspect='equal')

for x, y in np.ndindex(data.shape):
  plt.text(x, y, f'{x},{y}', color='black', ha='center', va='center')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there anything I can do to reduce lag with large number of text labels?